# java:25: '.class' expected error while merging arrays

Tags: java, arrays

Here is my code, it is asking me to call a class, I am confused as to do this. Noob to java, so any help would be greatly appreciated. line 25 is where the error occurs.
This program is merging two arrays together into a new array.

```
public class Merge{

   public static void main(String[] args){

        int[] a = {1, 1, 4, 5, 7};
        int[] b = {2, 4, 6, 8};

        int[] mergedArray = merge(a, b);

        for(int i = 0; i < mergedArray.length; i++){
            System.out.print(mergedArray[i] + " ");
        }

    }

    public static int[] merge(int[] a, int[] b){

        // WRITE CODE  HERE
        int[] mergedArray = new int[a.length[] + b.length[]];
        int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

        while (i < a.length() && j < b.length()) //error occurs at this line
        {
            if (a[i] < b[j])

             {

                 mergedArray[k] = a[i];
                 i++;

             }

             else

             {

                 mergedArray[k] = b[j];
                 j++;

             }

             k++;

         }

         while (i < a.length())

         {

             mergedArray[k] = a[i];
             i++;
             k++;

         }

         while (j < b.length())

         {

             mergedArray[k] = b[j];
             j++;
             k++;

         }

         return mergedArray;

    }

}
```

This program is merging two arrays together into a new array.

Comment: `int[] mergedArray = new int[a.length[] + b.length[]];` should be `int[] mergedArray = new int[a.length() + b.length()];`

Comment: Three different ways to get the length of an array are used in this code, and two of them are wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Get the length of an array without parenthesis.

```
a.length
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code, and it is actually working. You just have to change all of the length calls to just length (i.e remove length() and length[])

Other than that the code is functional. When run you get this output:

```
1 1 2 4 4 5 6 7 8
```